# ASP.Net 4 drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Using webmatix I am tyring to create dropdown list. but its giving me the error message.

```
@code

Dim items As New List(Of SelectListItem)()
items.Add(New SelectListItem() With { _
    .Text = "Swimming", _
    .Value = "1" _
})
items.Add(New SelectListItem() With { _
    .Text = "Cycling", _
     .Value = "2", _
     .Selected = True _
})
items.Add(New SelectListItem() With { _
    .Text = "Running", _
    .Value = "3" _
})


End code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @Html.TextBox("Name") <br/>
        @Html.DropDownList(@items) 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error message**

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected.

Source Error:



Line 26:     <body>
Line 27:         @Html.TextBox("Name") <br/>
Line 28:         @Html.DropDownList(@items) 
Line 29:     </body>
Line 30: </html>
```

can you point me, what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList(@items)
```

You are already within code block so

```
@Html.DropDownList(items)
```

should be enough